# How to use the MOQ library to mock an ENum

Tags: c#, enums, mocking, moq

I am having an issue using the Moq library to mock an Enum within my project.  I am trying to test a class and one of the methods accepts an ENum.  Is there any way to do this?

Here is the Enum I am trying to mock:

```
public enum PermissionType
{
   Create = 0,
   Read = 1,
   Update = 2,
   Delete = 3,
}
```

Here is the code I am trying to use to create the mock:

```
 private static Mock<PermissionService> GetMockPermissionService(bool hasPermissions)
 {
    var mockPermissionService = new Mock<PermissionService>();

    mockPermissionService.Setup(x => x.HasPermission(It.IsAny<string>(), 
                      **It.IsAny<PermissionType>()**)).Returns(hasPermissions);

    return mockPermissionService;
 }
```

This is the error I receive:

> System.ArgumentException: Invalid
>   setup on a non-overridable member: x
>   => x.HasPermission(It.IsAny(), It.IsAny())

I have also tried:

```
mockPermissionService.Setup(x => x.HasPermission(It.IsAny<string>(), 
                          **It.IsAny<int>()**)).Returns(hasPermissions);

mockPermissionService.Setup(x => x.HasPermission(It.IsAny<string>(), 
                          **PermissionType.Read**)).Returns(hasPermissions);
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means that your HasPermission method on PermissionService must be virtual, like so:

```
public virtual bool HasPermission(string name, PermissionType type)
{
   // logic
}
```